# Parsing a heredoc with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, heredoc

I have a Ruby method that uses Nokogiri to parse a heredoc. It currently looks like this and passes all specs:

```
def html_headers
  Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<-HTML)
  ....
  HTML
end
```

However, when I change it to the following, it fails the specs. I'm somewhat new to Ruby, so I'm not sure how this might change the result. Tests in console suggest it shouldn't change anything, that `str` should contain an equivalent string to the previous version of this method.

```
def html_headers
  str = <<-HTML
  ...
  HTML
  Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
end
```

Comment: This should work as-is. How is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting this question, I'll leave it as a record of my shame. The original code was actually

```
def html_headers
  Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<-HTML)
<div>...</div>
  HTML
end
```

and the code that was failing was

```
def html_headers
  str = <<-HTML
  <div>...</div>
  HTML
  Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
end
```

I thought indenting the heredoc to bring it inline with the rest of the method wouldn't have an effect. Silly me.